# Manipulating hardware textures with SDL2

Tags: c++, textures, sdl-2, pixel

Why do I have to use SDL_LockTexture and SDL_UnlockTexture to manipulate hardware textures with SDL2? I am aware of the difference between "STATIC" texture access and "STREAMING" texture access, but I guess I am confused because I seem to remember using "SDL_SetTextureColorMod" to adjust the color of "STATIC" textures. So, why is it that sometimes we have to lock pixels and sometimes we don't?

Answer (score 6):

You have to lock a texture in order to modify its pixels. `SDL_SetTextureColorMod` doesn't do this, it only sets a color which is multiplied with color of a pixel when the texture is used for rendering.

> Why do I have to use SDL_LockTexture and SDL_UnlockTexture to manipulate hardware textures?

"Hardware texture" means that pixels of a texture are stored in VRAM and can be directly accessed by a GPU when rendering. You can't modify VRAM memory directly. `SDL_LockTexture` returns pointer to buffer accessible by CPU, while `SDL_UnlockTexture` copies this (modified) buffer back to VRAM.